Calculated Column Syntax Error
I'm trying to filter out Choice Types that are Optional and Not Optional.  I am using a Task List on 2019 on prem.  I've used different formulas but they end up with syntax errors and I cannot save it.


What are the options of this "Choice Type" column? And where have you defined if which option is either optional or not-optional?

Hi @DikeshGandhi "Choice Type 1, Choice Type 2, Choice Type 3, Choice Type 4"
It's my first time using filtered views like this, I'm doing this at the request of a semi technical user so where should I have the "Optional"  "Not Optional" defined.
Thanks

It seems there is no OOTB options available. You can customize list forms using Power Apps and in that you can write logic to make few options are required and display validation message if user has not selected those options.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-apps/get-started/create-your-first-custom-form

@user79745 Are you just trying to show "Optional" and "Not Optional" as text results in your calculated column OR are you trying to make entries in any column/field optional/mandatory based on choice column?

@GaneshSanap-MVP wants to show Optional/Not Optional.  I figured out that it's the OR function that causing problems, just trying to figure out a way around an OR statement.

Is your choice column ("Choice Type") single selection field or allows multiple selections?

Single Selection, no fill in

Ok, try using solution given below. Let me know if it works or throws any errors.

If you want to show "Optional" as a result when "Choice Type" is either "Choice Type 1" OR "Choice Type 2" OR "Choice Type 3",
Try using calculated column formula like this:
=IF(OR([Choice Type]="Choice Type 1",[Choice Type]="Choice Type 2",[Choice Type]="Choice Type 3"),"Optional","Not Optional")

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].


You are awesome!  Finally got it to work.  Thanks!

You are welcome, glad it worked for you!
